# Android device monitor seems to miss crashes

Tags: android, android-studio, logcat, android-logcat

At seemingly random occasions it looks like Log cat in Device monitor bundled with Android studio misses error messages.

I have an app that crashed on different errors, `Index out of bounds` to mention one. At some occasions this crash was shown in the log, at other occasions it showed warnings, not errors. But it still crashed where expected at the out of bounds error.

I have no idea why the log misses those errors and what I should do to prevent it from happening. 
Any suggestions on what might be the reason, how I can find it and fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Logcat streams the log output from the device (or from an emulator) and that stream can be delayed, interrupted or just slow. When this happen I stop and restart it by clicking on this icon in Android Studio :

[image: Restart Logcat]

If it's from a device and this behavior is frequent you may also want to test an other cable.

Comment: It worked with the restart. Thanks. The question was about when using the emulator. Sad thing is I have no idea why it would be slow.

Comment: This is probably less logcat being slow and more DDMS being unreliable. This happens to me rather infrequently and I typically find that closing Android Studio, killing adb on my machine, killing the emulator, then bringing everything back up helps. It's not 100% fix but it sometimes works.

Comment: It happens to me a lot when I put my PC to sleep when the emulator is running. The connection is broken when my PC restarts and I have to shutdown the emulator and restart for it to connect again.